# mapping a curve equation to a staright line equation

Tags: matlab, math, matplotlib, curve-fitting, scilab

I dont know whether it is possible or not but i have a curve and i have found the equation of that curve now i want to map all the points on this curve to a straight line.
How it can be done ?

Curve Equation:

```
K3x^3 + k2x^2 + k1x + k0 = y
```

then what would be the corresponding equation of line which contains all the points which are in curve.
And if i make a equation of line by using end points of the curve then how do i map or fit all the points on that curve to this line.

for example I have attached an image, so can we make this curve to a straight line by using some kind of equation conversion. thanks[image]

I need output to be transformed as following image.
[image: trasformed image]

Comment: Do you mean you want to fit a straight line to the curve? If yes, polyfit function is your friend (http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/data_analysis/programmatic-fitting.html)

Comment: I have drawn that curve using polyfit and reading points from some other image, I want a reverse eqation which will map this equation to straight line

Comment: The reverse of `polyfit` is `polyval`. But I have no idea what you want to do.

Comment: Hmm, still not sure i got your question. Do you need an analytic transformation between your 3rd order polynomial and a straight line fit? Or just the straight line?

Comment: @Anshul your question is written in manner that you are searching equation of some line (which is not on the image) but I have the impression you want to find space transformation (curvature of space) that will transform your image to straight line (also unknown to which one) so please clarify and add the missing data to your question. idealy edit the image and add also the points order (direction) for both input curve and output line

Comment: @Anshul also is the polynomial generic or will it always have that shape?

Comment: @kostya  yes I dont need a straight line, drawing straight would be just pick first and last point and calculate slope of it and then draw it. I need an eqation that will transform my curve to straight line, Its kind of mapping. consider on curve each pixel different vslue, I want map all those value to line.

Comment: @pektre its generic polynomial, it will not have always that shape

Comment: @Spektre I have updated one more image, hope you get this question

Comment: @Anshul the line equation is easy `y=y0+(x-x0)*(y1-y0)/(x1-x0)` where (x0,y0),(x1,y1) are your curve endpoints. but if you need specific correspondence (non)linearity between curve and line points then this task is very hard. also if your curve is not function then use parametric equation of line... for specific (non)linear parameter you can use any type of polynomila curvature ...

Comment: @Anshul for generic transformation you need to sample line and curve by some parameter t (the same) and then interpolate between the two ..via cubic curve patches ...

Comment: @Anshul another option is get the parameter t as length from start in interval `<0,1>` ... that would be the best but the length on curve is curve integral ... so the complexity will be a bit bigger ...

Comment: Thanks  Spektre and Kostya, em done...

Answer (score 1):

So i did this by simply subtracting curve equation from line equation and then I got another equation(result of subtraction of equations) which i have used to map all the points of curve on to line.

```
void mapCurvePointsToLine(IplImage *img, double *coeff)
{
        // algo: mapping equation = line equation - curve equation 

        int i, y;
        double m;
        struct points p;
        p.x = malloc(sizeof(*p.x) * img->widthStep);
        p.y = malloc(sizeof(*p.y) * img->widthStep);
        p.np = img->widthStep;


        for( i = 0; i < img->widthStep; i++)  {
                y = round( (pow(i,3)*coeff[3]) + (pow(i,2)*coeff[2]) + (i*coeff[1]) + coeff[0]);

                p.x[i] = i;
                p.y[i] = y;
                img->imageData[(y*img->widthStep) + i] = 255u;
        }   

        //calculate slope and interspect of line
        m =  (p.y[(p.np - 1)] - p.y[0] ) / (p.x[(p.np - 1)] - p.x[0]);
        for( i = 0; i < img->widthStep; i++)  {

                y = p.y[i] + round( (pow(i,3)* (-1 * coeff[3]) ) + (pow(i,2)* ( -1 * coeff[2])) + (i* ( m - coeff[1]) ) ) ; 
                //y = y + round( (pow(i,3)* (-1 * coeff[3]) ) + (pow(i,2)* ( -1 * coeff[2])) ) ;
                img->imageData[(y*img->widthStep) + i] = 255u;
        }   
}
```

I got the result with some distortion in line, may be because of rounding the calculated values in integer.  See the output image i have attached.[image: mapped image to line from a curve]

Answer (score 0):

1. any 2D curve can be expressed like this:

   - `p(t)=p0+p1*t+p2*t*t+p3*t*t*t+...`
   - where `p,p0,p1,...` are vectors
   - `t` is parameter `<0,1>`
   - you already have this
   - `p.x(t)=x0+(x1-x0)*t+0*t*t+0*t*t*t;`
   - `p.y(t)=k0+k1*t+k2*t*t+k3*t*t*t;`
   - which is the same ...
   - `x0,x1` are your `x` constraints
2. you want q(p(t)) that lies on line `p(0)+(p(1)-p(0))*u;`

   - where `u` is parameter `<0,1>`
   - so if we assume that parameters `t,u` are proportional to curve distance from start
   - then `u=curve_distance(p(t),p(0))/curve_distane(p(1),p(0));`
   - so write function `curve_distance` that integrates the path length at interval <0,t>
   - and that is all you need
3. curve_distance

   - first you need to find the t parameter for each point
   - one point is always the start point so t0=0
   - the second you need to find from your parametric equations and input point coordinates
   - then just write for cycle with small enough step summing the distance
   - or solve it algebraically for used polynomial and compute directly in O(1)